# Having trouble clearing my setTimeout

Tags: javascript

```
var timer;
var object;
var thing;
var digit="0";

//this function fires when a single click occurs

function one(event){
   timer = setTimeout("AddDigit(object)",500);
   object = event;
}

//The AddDigit function keeps firing right after my double click function 
function AddDigit(x){
   object=x;
   if (eval(digit) == 0){ digit = object; }
   else{ digit = digit + object; }

   document.calculator.display.value = object;

}
// This function is supposed to stop the AddDigit function from firing...

document.ondblclick = function(button){
   clearTimeout(timer);

   thing=button.target;
   thing.setAttribute("class","duction");
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout("AddDigit(object)",500)`?, `eval(digit)`? Why?

Comment: @elclanrs. Didn't you like it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Double click dispatches two click events, *then* the double click event. The second time `one` gets called, it replaces `timer` with a new id, but the original timeout is still ready to go. When the dblclick handler gets called, it clears the second timeout, but not the first.

The solution is to clear any existing timeout in `one` before assigning `timer`.

```
function one(event)
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        AddDigit(event);
    }, 500);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/74qYF/

Comment: Don't forget to choose this as the answer!